# How do i make function that takes a pointer to a list of integers and returns 1 and if all elements in the list are odd, and 0

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct int_node IntNode;
struct int_node {
    int val;
    IntNode* next;
};

typedef struct int_list IntList;
struct int_list {
    IntNode* front;
};

int are_all_odd(IntList* list_ptr);

int main(void) {
    IntList list = create_list();

    insert_back(&list, 10);
    insert_back(&list, 71);
    insert_back(&list, 9);

    print_list(&list);
    free_list(&list);
    insert_back(&list, 5);

    insert_back(&list, 6);
    insert_back(&list, 7);
    insert_back(&list, 8);

    free_list(&list);

    return 0;
}

int are_all_odd(IntList* list_ptr){
    IntNode* current_node = list_ptr->front;

    if(current_node == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    while(current_node != NULL){
        if(current_node->val%2){
            return 0;
        }
```

Im currently working on the function are_all_odd and i want to have the function that takes a pointer to a list of integers and returns 1 if all elements in the list are odd, and 0 if all are even... but im not sure how to find the even numbers as it pops-up as an error... do i just to the same as val%2 for the return 0? or how should i foratt it? could anyone help suggest or give me an edited version of how i should fix it?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? What is `create_list`? What is `insert_back`? Where is the rest of the `are_all_odd` function? Any of those could be wrong and even if they are right we need complete code to be able to run and debug it ourselves. Please give a complete [mre] as well as the exact expected result vs actual result.

Comment: ok i edited it... is this better?

Comment: Could you give me like an example? or like give me suggestions on how i should work on it?

Comment: I have applied a consistent formatting to your code sample. From this it should be abundantly clear that it is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is testing whether the current value is odd, not whether it's even. You need to check if the modulus is equal to `0`.

If you make it through the loop without returning `0`, all the numbers must be odd, so you return `1` then.

There's no need for the `if` statement at the beginning, because the `while` loop will stop immediately if the list is empty, and you'll go to the `return 1` statement.

```
int are_all_odd(IntList* list_ptr){
    IntNode* current_node = list_ptr->front;
    
    while(current_node != NULL){
        if(current_node->val%2 == 0){
            return 0; 
        }
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
    return 1;
}
```